# Python, aiogram. Как реализовать анмацию в телеграм боте?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

**На официальном сайте [telegram](https://core.telegram.org/bots) для разработчиков, есть очень [интересный пример](https://core.telegram.org/file/464001127/10a99/GC0dSHYQTb0.3621529.mp4/75439f14147e13b6fb) анимации в боте.**

После выполнение определенной комманды экран телефона слегка блюрится и появляеться стикер.

> Ботов которые были указаны в примере не нашел (

Вообщем реально ли это вообше, и если да то как?

Comment: Это просто анимация от телеграма, боты так не могут

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://core.telegram.org/file/464001127/10a99/GC0dSHYQTb0.3621529.mp4/75439f14147e13b6fb
**Я разобрался, это анимация от  telegram, к боту применить её невозможно.**